# Getting the number of likes of an URL via PHP excluding the number of likes received in the comment section

Tags: php, facebook

I am currently getting the number of *likes* of an URL via the following PHP script:

```
<?php
$source_url = "[my-url-here]";  //This could be anything URL source including stripslashes($_POST['url'])

$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$shares =  $xml->link_stat->share_count;
$likes =  $xml->link_stat->like_count;
$comments = $xml->link_stat->comment_count;
$total = $xml->link_stat->total_count;
$max = max($shares,$likes,$comments);


echo "$source_url
<br><br>shares: $shares
<br><br>likes: $likes
<br><br>comments: $comments
<br><br>total: $total
<br><br>max: $max
<br>------------<br>
";

?>
```

The problem is that by `likes: $likes`, I don't just receive the number of *likes* of the URL, but I also get counted the number of *likes* received in the comments section (fb script).

I am currently managing a web contest, based on the number of *likes* a profile URL received, and some users are using this scheme (by giving many *likes* to the comments received by their profiles) to increase their chances of win.

So, how can I get the actual number of *likes* of the URL, without including the *likes* received by posts in the comment box section?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Facebook Open Graph to get number of *likes*:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.url.com/page
```

Another, more precise method is querying with FQL:

[Facebook Query Language Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql)

1. From `link_stat` table, using URL -  [link_stat Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/):

   ```
   SELECT like_count, comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url = "http://www.url.com/page"
   ```
2. Get `likes` for every comment from `comment` using `comments_fbid` as `object_id` - [comments Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/):

   ```
   SELECT likes FROM comment WHERE object_id = [comments_fbid]
   ```
3. Sum all `likes` from every comment and substract that total to `like_count`

Comment: The Open Graph shows exactly the same results as my code above. The FQL returns me to the same page, after alowing facebook to acces my details through my app. Could you post a sample full code?

Comment: Read the [implementation guides](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) of Facebook SDK, and try querys on [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Nice answer btw :P

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is how to get the actual number of *likes* of an **url** (excluding comments, comments likes, shares):

```
  $source_url="http://www.google.ro"; //the url you need

  //first get the total number of likes, and the comments_fbid that we will need in the next query

  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
  . 'fql?q=SELECT+like_count,comments_fbid+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url="' . $source_url . '"';
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);


  //place them in 2 variables to use
  $like_total=$fql_query_obj["data"][0]["like_count"];
  $object_id=$fql_query_obj["data"][0]["comments_fbid"];

  echo $like_total;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $object_id;


   //execute next query from the *comment* table to get the array of *likes* in the comment section
   $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . 'fql?q=SELECT+likes+FROM+comment+WHERE+object_id=' . $object_id;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

//sum out the results in the array
$nr=count($fql_query_obj["data"]);  
  $s=0;
  for($i=0;$i<$nr;$i++)
  { $s+=$fql_query_obj["data"][$i]["likes"];   }


$therealnumberoflikes=$like_total-$s;
echo $therealnumberoflikes;
```